# Change button from left to right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the  button place from left to right and I've tried like following
but just the text is floating to the right("This is to the right") not the button("Create new"),how should I change it
to be in the right place?

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="float:right;">This is to the right</div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the  `style="float:right;"` in the paragraph tag as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align:right;` should do the trick, if you want everything within the div to be aligned to the right ...

```
<div style="width:100%;float:right; text-align:right;">
    <div>This is to the right</div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you meant by two `style` attributes? What should do float with 100% width?

You need to float the button. Eg. `p {float: right}`.

Answer (score 0):

To stay Bootstrap friendly, you use Bootstrap classes instead of inline styling whenever possible:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-right"> 
  <div>This is to the right</div>
  <p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
</div>
```

col-xs-12 = 100% width

text-right = everything inside is aligned right